# Copy and past data from all files in a folder to master file in same folder

Tags: vba, loops, directory, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a specific range of data from SAME tab `d. Rate Card` in 3 different worksheets named "RCR Schedule C - Rate Card.xls" in one folder and paste in master file named "RFP consolidation macro". 
I created the loop and am able to copy/paste from the 1st file in the folder but not the other 2. Below is the code for that. Is there any way to ensure the code works for all the files in the folder and not only the first one?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow

MyFile = Dir("c:\Users\s4043091\Desktop\New folder\RFP\NEW\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "RFP consolidation macro.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

'Workbooks.Open ("c:\Users\s4043091\Desktop\New folder\RFP\NEW\RCR Schedule C - Rate Card.xls")

Workbooks("RCR Schedule C - Rate Card.xls").Worksheets("d. Rate Card").Range("b3:ah482").Copy _
  Workbooks("RFP consolidation macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Masterfile-Rate Card").Range("b1")

Workbooks("RCR Schedule C - Rate Card.xls").Worksheets("a. Company Background").Range("e7").Copy _
  Workbooks("RFP consolidation macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Masterfile-Rate Card").Range("a4:a482")

'Range("A2:D200").Copy
'ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Macro").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: no need to reinvent the wheel: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response! But I wanted a MACROS with the above mentioned function and not an add-in as we have to iterate the process every month for different sheets

Comment: Did you bother looking at the code in the add-in and try to understand it and adapt it to your needs?

Comment: No, because there are already a 1000 templates freely available and I don't need another example but rather a more specific solution to my issue because of which I am in this forum. Hello?

Comment: You say you wan to loop "worksheets" and then you say "tabs" worksheets and tabs are the same thing. Are you wanting to loop workbooks in a folder and extract from sheets in those workbooks having the same name? If that is the case then I'd suggest you use the `FileSystemObject` to loop the files in a folder instead of `Dir()`. That may be where you issue is.

Comment: Yes, I want to loop workbooks in a folder and extract from sheets in those workbooks having the same name. I even tried using filesystemobject but its still no working. I feel I am stuck with a minor issue but can't make out what it is!

Comment: Did you (try to) use early or late binding when using FileSystemObject?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should get you going:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoopFilesInFolderEarlyFSO()
    'Early Bound - requires Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime; with the reference there is Intellisense
    'the Early Bound part:
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject

    'Everything after is the same:
    Dim myFolderPath As String
    myFolderPath = "C:\thePath"
    If FSO.FolderExists(myFolderPath) Then
        Dim myFolder As Folder
        Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(myfoderpath)
    Else
        GoTo ExitSub
    End If
    Dim currFile As File
    For Each currFile In myFolder.Files
        Debug.Print currFile.Name
    Next
ExitSub:

End Sub
Public Sub LoopFilesInFolderLateFSO()
    'Late Bound - requires Creating the FSO; without the reference there is no Intellisense

    'the Late Bound part:
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Everything after is the same:
    Dim myFolderPath As String
    myFolderPath = "C:\thePath"
    If FSO.FolderExists(myFolderPath) Then
        Dim myFolder As Folder
        Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(myfoderpath)
    Else
        GoTo ExitSub
    End If
    Dim currFile As File
    For Each currFile In myFolder.Files
        Debug.Print currFile.Name
    Next
ExitSub:

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out the time to respond! I am getting error- 'user defined type not defined' in the 1st line of code itself "FSO As FileSystemObject" I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime?

Comment: I got it solved using dir() itself, but thanks for all your help!